# jsp album can be resolved to a type

Tags: java, sql, jsp

i am sure that I have put the album in my package, but it still has this error:

org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to compile class for JSP

An error occurred at line: 38 in the jsp file: /albums.jsp
Generated servlet error:
album cannot be resolved to a type

An error occurred at line: 38 in the jsp file: /albums.jsp
Generated servlet error:
album cannot be resolved to a type

An error occurred at line: 38 in the jsp file: /albums.jsp
Generated servlet error:
Duplicate local variable album

```
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:510)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:375)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:314)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:264)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:802)
```

---

---

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<%@ page import="java.util.*" %>
<%@ page import="javax.servlet.*" %>
<%@ page import="java.lang.*" %>
<%@ page import="photoshare.NewUserDao" %>
<jsp:useBean id="newUserBean"
class="photoshare.NewUserBean" />
<jsp:setProperty name="newUserBean" property="*"/>

<%@ page import="photoshare.NewAlbumDao" %>
<jsp:useBean id="album"
         class="photoshare.Album" />
```

```
<html>
<head><title>Album and Pictures</title></head>
 <body>
<h2>Create a New Album </h2>
<form action="/photoshare/createalbum.jsp?NewAlbumName=" target="_blank" method="get">
  Album Name: <input type="text" name="NewAlbumName"/>
  <input type="submit" value="Create"/><br/>
</form>
<h2>Your Albums</h2>
<tr>
<%
NewUserDao newUserDao = new NewUserDao();
NewAlbumDao newAlbumDao = new NewAlbumDao();
String owner_email = request.getUserPrincipal().getName();
int owner_id = newUserDao.getUserID(owner_email);
List<String> albumName = new ArrayList<String>();
albumName = newAlbumDao.getYourAlbumsName(owner_id);
List<album> albumList = new ArrayList<album>();
albumList = newAlbumDao.getYourAlbums(owner_id);
for (String album:albumList) {%>
    <a href="yourAlbum.jsp?album_id=<%= album.getAlbumID() %> & album_name= <%= album.getName()%>"> <%= album.getName()%></a></br>
<%}%>
</tr>
<h4>Return to<a href="index.jsp">Home</a></h4>
</body>
</html>
```

It seems it didn't work when I restart the tomcat service, thanks for answering!!!

Answer (score 0):

Please look at the line:

```
List<album> albumList = new ArrayList<album>();
```

album has been defined as a bean in your JSP. However in the List definition, you need to provide a class name.

I believe you need to change this line to:

```
List<photoshare.Album> albumList = new ArrayList<photoshare.Album>();
```

Comment: Thank you, but i am not really know what you asked me to do, did you mean change the List<album> albumList = new ArrayList<album>(); to List albumList = new ArrayList(); ?  @Rahul Phadnis

Comment: It didn't work,is there any errors in my tomcat settings? @Rahul Phadnis

Comment: Please post the complete stack trace.